# Extracting information from captured image in android

Tags: android, image-processing, text-extraction

This is my image:

[image]

I used this link(tessaract) to capture and process the image:
http://kurup87.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html

But this is the issue, if this entire area is scanned, the return values are some garbage values, not accurate. But if I scan V516990, 2653, and the date separately. results are correct.

My intention is to scan V516990 and 2653 in one go, without the user having to use the camera twice. Any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the user take one image only
You can store it in memory and set region of interest to top portion and then extract it
Use cvSetImageROI

https://github.com/mintuhouse/FinMan/blob/master/src/unix/imp.cpp

Check line 337, when you pass IplImage to tesseract
set your region (top or bottom parts in your case) of interest on image
Check 297 here

https://github.com/mintuhouse/FinMan/blob/master/src/unix/main.cpp

This function does main text extraction in out case
use JNI
java native interface

or even better use javacv
OpenCV port in Java
we realized it later. It make life a lot simpler